# rolling snapshot of pictures taken in the last half hour

Tags: find, cp

I've taken this:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -mtime +1 -type f -exec cp '{}' backup \;
```

Which should copy all the regular files in the current directory more than 1 day old to the directory backup (assuming the directory backup exists).

And this:

```
find . -mmin -40
```

Which should find files modified in the last 40mins.

To give this:

```
find -mmin -30 -exec cp '{}' backup \;
```

But I'm not sure what to do next.

How can I modify the above statement to copy all files and directories from `/nmt` to `/home/pi/box/street_pictures` for the last 30 min, overwriting what was previously in
`/home/pi/box/street_pictures`.

I, in effect, want half an hour rolling snapshot of pictures taken and placed in the `/nmt` directory to be present in the `/home/pi/box/street_pictures` directory.

If I run this command each min, is it possible to do this so I don't have to clear the directory and re-copy the full hour each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy the files that are less than 30 minutes old (but don't overwrite files):

```
find /nmt/ -cmin -30 -type f -exec cp -pn '{}' /home/pi/box/street_pictures/ \;
```

Then to remove files in `/home/pi/box/street_pictures` that are older than 30 minutes

```
find /home/pi/box/street_pictures -cmin +30 -type f -exec rm '{}' \;
```

If each of these acts as you like you could put them in a script and run that script in cron each minute or whatever time window you feel is best.

Comment: this looks good, but can it be modified to copy and delete files based on creation date, not modification date?

Comment: I think you just need to change -mmin to -cmin I'll change it in the answer